# Reading .csv scientific notation

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to read this .csv file and here is an example of the data:

```
1.33286E+12 0   -20.790001  -4.49   -0.762739   -3.364226   -8.962189

1.33286E+12 0   -21.059999  -4.46   -0.721878   -3.255263   -8.989429
```

The problem is with the first column  row 1 and 2. In the excel file it says the numbers in the cells are displayed as 1.33286E+12 and when you click on the cell it says they are 1332856031313 and 1332856031328 but the program is reading them as 1.33286E+12 but I need the whole number 1332856031313 and 1332856031328.

The code:

```
inputfile.open(word1.c_str());
while (getline (inputfile, line)) //while line reads good
{
  istringstream linestream(line); //allows manipulation of string
  string str;

while (getline (linestream, item, ',')) //extract character and store in item until ','
    {

  char * cstr, *p; 
  cstr = new char [item.size()+1]; 
  strcpy(cstr, item.c_str()); 
  p = strtok(cstr, " "); 

  while (p!=NULL) //while not at the end loop
    {      // double e = atof(p); // coverts p to double
        value++;
        if( value == 1)
                {     double e = atof(p); // coverts p to double
          if(m ==1)
          cout << time[0]<<"\n";

          ostringstream str1;
           str1 << e;
          str = str1.str();
          string str2;
          str2.append(str.begin(), str.end());
          const char * convert = str2.c_str();
          e = atof(convert);
         time[m] = e*0.001;
          m++;
          //if(m >=192542)
          //cout << time[m-1]<<"\n";

        }

               p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
  delete[] cstr; //delete cstr to free up space.
}
count ++;
value = 0;
}
inputfile.close();
```

Comment: The problem is not in the reader, it is in the writer. You must get your CSV generator (excel, presumably?) to write its values out at full precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number 1332856031313 is being serialised as 1.33286E+12, there is no way to get it back in the deserialisation process. Information in the form of those 6 extra significant digits is gone forever. You need to make sure that when the CSV file is generated, it is saved at full precision. I don't know how you might do this with Excel.

Also, your use of `atof` and `const char*` isn't very C++-esque. Consider using code like

```
double a, b, c, d;
linestream >> a >> b >> c >> d;
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rook has beaten me to it, but I will make one suggestion.  Use a loop for decoding, testing on the stringstream status.  OK, two suggestions: break your code into functions.  Putting it all in one big lump makes it harder to understand.

```
    void DecodeLine(const std::string &sLine, 
                    std::vector<double> &vResults)
    {
        std::istringstream istr(sLine);
        double d = 0;
        istr >> d;
        while (!istr.fail())
        {
            vResults.push_back(d);
            istr >> d;
        }
    }
```